# setOnClickListener Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, methods

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

OnClickListener list1 = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class));
    }
};

b1.setOnClickListener(list1);
```

How come we don't need to instantiate or initialize the View v which is passed to onClick? What object does it refer to?

Answer (score 3):

The `View v` is actually the `Button b1` if you press the button

If you press the button, `View v` will return the Object `Button b1`

Comment: but then why don't we pass the Button b1?

Comment: @naxchange - its not you, who explicity passes the View to **onClick()** method. Its done by your listener which you have bound to your button which does that, in case of any **onClick** event trigger.

Answer (score 0):

android treat every element i.e textfield,button etc as views. here View v will return the object for the button which you are clicking i.e Button b1.

Answer (score 0):

`b1.setOnClickListener(list1);` - This code of yours binds the `list1` listener to your button `b1`'s event of onClick.

Whenever there is a click - in this case - **a touch**, on the button b1, the `onClick()` method will be called which sends the `handle(v)` of the view which has triggered it(in your case - **button b1**).

Hence, the `View v` will be your handle to the view triggering the `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

test the following..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListerner(this);
    .....
    .....
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
     if(v == b1)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The code above and your code are both the same.  When you press the button, the reference of button object is passed in to onClick().